# How to check if a span is a parent of another span, then destroy the child span?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Let's say I have the following:

> Hi, my `<span class='green_mark'>` name is `<span class='red_mark'>`Bob`</span>`. How are `</span>` you doing?

In this example, green_mark already covers the content of red_mark. Is there some way to detect if a span parent covers a span child? Then, destroy the span that is the child?

In this case, I see that `.green_mark` is the parent, `.red_mark` is the child. Therefore, I want `.red_mark` destroyed.

**Note:** I have the highlighting done in JS, but send data over PHP. Therefore, this solution can either be JS or PHP...

Comment: DOM is a tree. Every tree node knows what its parents/descendants are. So find your "red_mark" node and start moving up the tree - if you reach the top and don't find "green_mark", then they're not nested

Comment: @MarcB The spans are dynamic and are based on highlighting. I don't want to look for a particular span, because their are multiple colors. I want to find the child of the parent because their could be multiple parent child relationships in one passage of text...

Comment: doesn't matter. it's still a tree. Traverse the tree to see if your specific conditions are/aren't met, and do something based on that.

Comment: @GreatDayToday I know this was marked as answered however depending how how many highlighted classes the code below might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span.green_mark>span.red_mark").each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    var text = elem.text();
    elem.replaceWith(text);
  });
});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span.green_mark span.red_mark").each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    var text = elem.text();
    elem.replaceWith(text);
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/1502/

The first code works for the immediate `red_mark` child of `green_mark` while the second one is for any `red_mark` child within `green_mark`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this with jQuery.

```
$('span.green_mark').find('span').remove()
```

Comment: Excellent approach. The problem is that `.green_mark` is not always the parent, it could be `.yellow_mark`. Therefore, I need to base this solution on a parent, not on a particular span. In the same way, the child could be any color, not just `.red_mark`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove span tag that are directly children :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("button").on("click",function(){

         $("span").children().remove("span");

     })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span>I am Parent.<span>I am Children</span></span>
    <br><br>
    <button>Remove</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        
$(document).ready(function(){
    
     $("button").on("click",function(){
         
         $("span").children().remove("span");
    
     })
})
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If want remove span children,grandchild,....

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("button").on("click",function(){

         $("span").find("span").remove();

     })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span>I am Parent.
        <div>I am div
            <span>I am grandChild</span>
        </div>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <button>Remove</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        
$(document).ready(function(){
    
     $("button").on("click",function(){
         
         $("span").find("span").remove();
    
     })
})
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code would unwrap all span elements that contain _mark in in their className. Regardless wether the parent was red_mark, yellow_mark, rainbow_mark.

```
$("span[class*=_mark] span[class*=_mark]").contents().unwrap();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sx07La3h/

**Starting HTML:**

```
<span> Hi, my <span class='green_mark'> name is <span class='red_mark'>Bob <span class='yellow_mark'>Smith</span></span>. How are </span> you doing?</span>
```

**Ending HTML:**

```
<span> Hi, my <span class="green_mark"> name is Bob Smith. How are </span> you doing?</span>
```